# Running Matlab GUI from Different Directory

Tags: matlab, user-interface, directory

I've only been working with Matlab for a bit over a year now, and I've run into a problem I can't seem to overcome.

I've used Guide to create several GUIs. There is a Main GUI and a few "sub" GUIs that can be opened from the Main GUI using a Dropdown Menu.

All of this works perfectly fine when the GUIs are in the same directory. However, I am trying to organize it so the Main GUI is in one folder, and all the GUI's that it opens are in another. Ideally, I am trying to make it so that I can open multiple GUIs from the Main GUI and operate them while being able to open new GUIs anytime I want.

---

I've tried several methods that don't work, including the following:

run('./directory1/sub_gui1');

This can open the GUI, but doesn't allow me to actually use the GUI because I am in the wrong directory.

run('./directory1/sub_gui1');
cd('./directory1');

This can open the GUI and allows me to use it, but makes it so I cannot use the Main GUI anymore, because I am no longer in its directory.

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Add it to your path with `addpath` or `pathtool`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) so that Matlab can find all the sub GUIs or you can put them in a sub-directory of the main GUI directory called [private](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

`addpath(genpath('./directory1/'))` will add directory1 and all subfolders to the MATLAB path.

You may want to stick a line in the "main GUI" to do something like that. E.g., you could use `mfilename` to find the location of the main gui function and add its folder to the path.

I like the private folder idea from Molly too.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I didn't expect that something I'd pondered over for so long would just have such a simple solution!